# Dynamically setting of cells' NumberFormat in VBA excel when the uncertainty calculation in consideration

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I need to dynamically set the NumberFormat, via VBA, to imported text file values, as just below:

Imported values number type is "General", so I want to change to "Number", but preserve the decimal point

```
12.324 ............................ 3 decimal points  
2.12 .............................. 2 decimal points  
0.00123 ............................5 decimal points  
12.1234567 ........................ 7 decimal points
```

And all the data in the same column.

Code is simple:

```
Range("A1").Numberformat ="##0.0##"
Range("A2").Numberformat ="#0.0#"
Range("A3").Numberformat ="#0.0####"
Range("A4").Numberformat ="##0.0######"
```

So, I need to dynamically set "#".

The reason for setting the number after decimal point is very important for calculating the uncertainty result. In calculations, there is a need for the resolution which means how many digits after the decimal point appears on the measurement device that doing calibrations.

---

I found a solution.

```
  res_dec_point = Len(Split(res_val & ",", ",")(1))
  kes_dec_point = Len(Split(kes_val & ",", ",")(1))

  MyNumberFormat_res = "0."
  For i_num = 1 To res_dec_point
    MyNumberFormat_res = MyNumberFormat_res & "0"
  Next i_num
  
  MyNumberFormat_kes = "0."
  For i_num = 1 To kes_dec_point
    MyNumberFormat_kes = MyNumberFormat_kes & "0"
  Next i_num
```

Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/10968406/bdra

Comment: Your question is not clear, but each cell has its own `.NumberFormat` property you can set it in code easily. Did you try that? You did not include any code in your question so it is difficult to help you.

Comment: You do not need the `#` signs - just remove them. To format to 5 decimals you just use `"0.00000" - setting them dynamically depends on how you are determining how many decimal places you want, and you did not include that in your question.

Comment: every number has it's decimal places as seen. So it is difficult to set. Every number different accuracy so need dynamically setting decimal point. 12.12 not equal 12.12000.

Comment: If you want them to each show their original format then do not use ANY formatting.

Comment: BUT how can I convert to number format? General format is not suitable. Since I need the accuracy of the decimal.

Comment: General format preserves the full precision of the number, including all decimals. I guess what we are trying to understand is why you need to change the format.

Comment: Ok. Depending on the number decimal point accuracy some generated data MUST be set the accuracy that we are talking about. And some Uncertainty calculation need and directly depends on the decimal point accuracy. In order to make such a calculation and set the other generated data accuracy, I am using .NumberFormat property to get the decimal point accuracy and apply it to generated data.

Comment: The number format does not change the value in the cell. it only changes the show value (by rounding the value for display, if needed), the value itself is not changed by using this formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, as I understand it, your code needs to read decimal numbers formatted as string values, then write them to destination cells formatted as decimal numbers. Each destination cell needs to be formatted  with as many decimal places as are present in the original string value.

You did not include your code in the question, so I will not provide completed code in response, but in outline here is a way to approach it:

1. Identify the number of decimal places in the original string value. Use the `Instr` function to locate the decimal point, then count the number of numerals to the right of the decimal point.
2. Number formats themselves are expressed as string values. For instance, in `Range("A1").Numberformat ="0.0"`, the "0.0" part is a string. You can utilize this to your advantage. Either look up or dynamically generate a string value that expresses the required number format for each cell.
3. Assign the number format to the destination cell.

Here is a snippet that generates and assigns a number format with a variable number of decimal places:

```
Dim MyNumberFormat As String, NumberOfDecimals As Integer
    
MyNumberFormat = "0."
    
For i = 1 To NumberOfDecimals
    MyNumberFormat = MyNumberFormat & "0"
Next

MyWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = MyNumberFormat
```

I believe this answers the core of your question. You will need to build it out with your own code, define what happens if NumberOfDecimals is 0, etc.

Comment: Thank you that is what I am looking for.  MyNumberFormat = MyNumberFormat & "0"

Comment: @iincitr: OK, good. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of a value does not change the value

[image]

In this example we calculate `2/3`, and show it using 'General format', and using 3,4, or 5 decimals.

On the last line we substract `0.666` from the values in the first line. The green values are all in 'General format'.

Conclusion: The formatting does not change the value!

Comment: Thank you but the accuracy is important me. Please consider ActiveWorkbook.PrecisionAsDisplayed = True

Comment: The reason for setting the number after the decimal point is very important for calculating the uncertainty result. In calculations, there is a need for the resolution which means how many digits after the decimal point appears on the measurement device that doing calibrations.

Comment: You should note that applying a NumberFormat to a cell does not change the **value** that is in the cell. It just changes the way it is formatted.  When you really want to round to, i.e. 3 decimals, you should do `ROUND(<value>,3)` or `ROUNDDOWN(<value>,2)` Depending on how you want the rounding to be done.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I am not considered "VALUE" I am considered the way of formated digit number after decimal point char ( . or , depends on regional format ). This is called " resolution " on calibration budget calculating and calibration uncertainty calculations.

Comment: You need to get the number of digits after the `.`.  This can be done with the formula: `=IF(C18=INT(C18),0,LEN(C18)-FIND(".",C18,1))`  (where C18 has i.e. the value `12.7654321`, then this function will return `7`)  When formatting (after the `.`), you start with a `0`, and then repeat and `#` for the output of this function minus 1 times)